# Preview function for promoted results

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, promoted-results

I have some promoted results for my search. It's working and it displays my documents with a checkbox logo to the left. However i dont have the preview function on hover for my promoted documents. Is it possible to add preview for promoted results, maybe with css?

Answer (score 0):

The Promoted Result Display template does not include that feature. If you want you can add it yourself by creating a custom display template.